# How to delete a deceased person’s Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

My Mother passed away and I need to deleted her two Facebook accounts.  Someone hacked one of the accounts and is sending out friend request. Nothing from Facebook’s help site works. How can I delete her account?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for you loss. You can [Report a Deceased Person](https://www.facebook.com/help/408583372511972/) to Facebook.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/265593773453448):

> **How do I ask a question about a deceased person's account on Facebook?**
>
> We can help with questions or requests from family members, including requests to remove their loved one's account. Learn more about what happens when [an account is removed](https://www.facebook.com/help/125338004213029?helpref=faq_content) from Facebook.
>
> If you'd like to submit a question or request regarding your loved one's account, please [contact us](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/228813257197480).

You can directly [Report Compromised Account](https://www.facebook.com/hacked).

You can learn more about [Hacked Accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/hacked).